# Postgresql data recovery encoding

Tags: windows, postgresql-9.5

I can't recover a database script.

I have followed different posts and this is what I've done so far to solve this:

1- dump UTF-8 old database to LATIN9:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.22\pg_dump" -E LATIN9 --no-owner --no-acl -U postgres -W -h localhost -p 5432 database_name > database_name.sql
```

2- Remove the old database

```
DROP DATABASE database_name;
```

3- Create the new database as LATIN9:

```
CREATE DATABASE "database_name" WITH ENCODING='LATIN9' OWNER=username TEMPLATE=template0 LC_COLLATE='C' LC_CTYPE='C' CONNECTION LIMIT=-1;
```

4- I try to recover the LATIN9 script created in the first step with the next command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.22\psql.exe" -U username-d database_name -f database_name.sql
```

And then I get the error message:

> psql: FATAL:  conversion between WIN1252 and LATIN9 is not supported

I don't understand, the script is already LATIN9!!! What's going on?
I want to add that what I'm trying to archive with this is to change my current UTF-8 database to LATIN9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work I changed the steps 1 and 4.
This are all the steps with the corrections:

1-

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.22\pg_dump" --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --role "postgres" --no-password  --format tar --blobs --encoding LATIN9 --verbose --file "database_name.backup" "database_name"
```

2-

```
DROP DATABASE database_name;
```

3-

```
CREATE DATABASE "database_name" WITH ENCODING='LATIN9' OWNER=username TEMPLATE=template0 LC_COLLATE='C' LC_CTYPE='C' CONNECTION LIMIT=-1;
```

4-

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.22\pg_restore" --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --dbname "database_name" --role "postgres" --no-password  --verbose "database_name.backup"
```